# .NET Regex question

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'm trying to parse some data out of a website. The problem is that a javascript generates the data, thus I can't use a HTML parser for it. The string inside the source looks like:

```
<a href="http:www.domain.compid.php?id=123">
```

Everything is constant except the id that comes after the =. I don't know how many times the string will occur either. Would appreciate any help and an explanation on the regex example if possible.

Comment: If you can pass it to regex, why can't you pass it to a proper parser?

Comment: Because the source is screwed by the javascript unicode characters such as "\u003A" and HtmlAgilityPack does not work with javascript either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to save any of it? A blanket regex `href="[^"]+">` will match the entire string. If you need to save a specific part, let me know.

EDIT: To save the id, note the paren's after `id=` which signifies to capture it. Then to retrieve it, use the match object's Groups field.

```
string source = "a href=\"http:www.domain.compid.php?id=123\">";
Regex re = new Regex("href=\"[^\"]+id=([^\"]+)\">");

Match match = re.Match(source);
if(match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's a match!\nI found:{0}", match.Groups[0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("And the id is {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

EDIT: example using `MatchCollection`

```
MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(source);

foreach(Match m in mc)
{
    //do the same as above. except use "m" instead of "match"
    //though you don't have to check for success in each m match object 
    //since it wouldn't have been added to the MatchCollection if it wasn't a match
}
```

Comment: @jb Hm thanks, that looks great. However I'm not sure how I am supposed to use the value as pattern because of the double quotes inside it. I thought by using the verbatim @ string but it doesn't compile(Invalid expression term ')' and same for ^

Comment: @regexnewb I updated my answer with an example. You would need to escape the `"` in the regex by doing `\"`

Comment: @jb thanks that works, is it possible to only parse out the value after id = ?

Comment: @regexnewb, sure, so in this case you want to save the "123", right?

Comment: @jb thanks, that works for a single match. If i would use a MatchCollection how would I be able to get the id from it? Since I have multiple links and I guess that I need to use a MatchCollection to "collect" them all.

Comment: @regexnewb, updated. I don't think I've ever edited an answer that many times :)

Comment: @jb sorry for taking your time lol, but I am finally letting you free. It works just as I wanted, thank you very much.

Comment: @regexnewb, no problem at all, glad to help. Good luck on your project and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

This does the parsing in javascript and creates a csv-string:

```
var re = /<a href="http:www.domain.compid.php\?id=(\d+)">/;
var source = document.body.innerHTML;
var result = "result: ";

var match = re(source);
while (match != null) {
    result += match[1] + ",";
    source = source.substring(match.index + match[0].length);
    match = re(source);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grastveit/cdDLC/). If the html-content is not used for anything else on the server it should be sufficient to send the ids.

**EDIT**, For performance and reliability it's probably better to use builtin javascript-functions (or jQuery) to find the urls instead of searching the entire content:

```
var re = /www.domain.compid.php\?id=(\d+)/;
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');    
var result = "result: ";

for (var i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {
    var match = re(as[i].getAttribute('href'));
    if (match != null) {
        result += match[1] + ",";
    }
}
```